# Another 'Could not find your craft/ folder' on fresh install

Tags: installation

Even though I repeatedly downloaded the current Craft release, created a new host with a new root folder and a new database, installing Craft runs into the error `Could not find your craft/ folder etc ...` when I try launch whateverdomain.dev/admin.

Followed the instructions step by step each and every time, applied the right permissions to each folder (and its contents).

None of the earlier posts come up with a fix to this issue. Could this be a MAMP issue?

– Richard

[image]

Comment: Okay, I just installed Craft on a 'live' server (craft.ontwerpzaam.nl), and quest what ... it works. It seems to be a local problem, so my next step will be uninstall & reinstall MAMP locally, let's see what that brings us ...

Comment: I uninstalled MAMP, reinstalled a fresh copy, and just started from scratch installing Craft. Although I had to use 777 permissions on the craft, app, config and storage folders, it now works. Apparently something was corrupted in MAMP.

Comment: Huh... weird.  Would you mind adding what worked for you as a official answer, Richard?  It might help someone else in the future.